# Why isn't "sexual harassment" a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have a question about my Law Stack Exchange post: [Is calling a tenant "babe" sexual harassment?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/10935/is-calling-a-tenant-babe-sexual-harassment)

Why isn't "sexual harassment" a tag?

I know it's different from sexual assault and has it's own category under "harassment" so why doesn't it have a tag?

Answer (score 1):

Tags tend to disappear if they don't have more than one question.  If you list a few other questions to which it should apply I'll create it.

Comment: Here's one it could apply to: [Is forceless groping illegal in Germany?](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/6554/136)

Comment: @curiousdannii - No, that's definitely assault.